# Check if two strings have same characters in order

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I write a function in javascript that would return the number of letters shared between two strings (in order).

eg: if the two strings are `read` and `bread`, it should return 4.

I'm thinking of using loops somehow but it seems it would be very convoluted with a lot of iterations, and I'm not sure where to begin.

Is there a way to achieve this using regex? Possibly, get the substring that matches? The length can then be derived from `substring.length`

Comment: I added an implementation to my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Pseudocode) for the Longest Common Substring problem is kind of tricky. I don't think there is an easy way do do the equivalent with regex.

Comment: Well the generalized version, where the "strings" have an unbounded "character set" (like, if they're arrays of integers), seems harder than when the character set is of a manageable size.

Comment: @Pointy: You basically just need to use a hash-table to store the character->value pairs instead of using the characters as indices in an array. There is a litle note about that in the Wikipedia article I linked.

Comment: Thank you! The algorithm was the perfect start. I can code that into JS now.

Comment: @missingno well what I mean is that if you can cheaply compute the common characters, you can skip a lot of comparisons; in other words, you can know not to bother with certain potential matching substrings.

Comment: @Pointy: forget what I said, the algorithm does not depend on the character set (-_-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of the other algorithmic answers.

That being said, here is a regex driven solution just for fun. Implemented in Perl for convenience, same expression will work in JavaScript.

```
sub longest_common_substr_len{
    my $s = "$_[0]|$_[1]";
    my $l = 0;

    $l = length > $l? length: $l for $s =~ /(?=([^|]+)(?=[^|]*\|[^|]*\1))./g;

    return $l;
}
```

The regex finds all* common substrings, and the loop gets the maximum length.

It works by concatenating both strings with a special delimiter (which cannot be present in the strings, `|` in this case), then use the regex to find ("locally longest") substrings (at every char) that are both before and after the delimiter.

The outer lookahead encapsulation is used to advance only one char at a time. Without it "zomg" and "zoomg" would only give 2, because "zo" in "zomg" already been consumed without allowing "omg" to match.

[Example usage](http://ideone.com/GduHz):

```
say longest_common_substr_len "read", "bread";
say longest_common_substr_len "omgzomg", "omgomg";
say longest_common_substr_len "zomg", "zoomg";
```

Output:

```
4
3
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what I would do would be:

1. Find the set of characters that are in both strings
2. For each of those, find the longest matching substring for each instance of the character

Finding the characters in common would be just a linear pass through each string, building sets, and then intersecting the sets. It'd help to keep track not only of the characters but also of the indexes (positions in the strings).  That way, when you're doing the second part, you wouldn't have to search the strings to find the characters again.

Don't vote for this yet; wait until somebody smarter gives it a try :-)  (Well you can vote me down of course.)

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvhYc/) with an implementation.  Here's the JavaScript function that does the work:

```
function longestSharedSequence(str1, str2) {
    var seqs = {
        longest: null,
        all: []
    };

    function setOfChars(s) {
        var rv = {},
            c;
        for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
            c = s[i];
            if (rv[c]) rv[c].push(i);
            else rv[c] = [i];
        }
        return rv;
    }

    function intersect(set1, set2) {
        var rv = {};
        for (var c in set1) {
            if (set1.hasOwnProperty(c) && set2.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
                rv[c] = [set1[c], set2[c]];
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }

    function getSeq(pos1, pos2) {
        var seq = [str1[pos1]],
            i, j;
        for (i = pos1 + 1, j = pos2 + 1; i < str1.length && j < str2.length && str1[i] === str2[j]; ++i, ++j)
        seq.push(str1[i]);
        return seq.join('');
    }

    function getSeqs(positions) {
        var i, j, p1 = positions[0],
            p2 = positions[1],
            seq;
        for (i = 0; i < p1.length; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < p2.length; ++j) {
                seq = getSeq(p1[i], p2[j]);
                seqs.all.push(seq);
                if (seqs.longest === null || seq.length > seqs.longest.length) {
                    seqs.longest = seq;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var set = intersect(setOfChars(str1), setOfChars(str2));

    for (var c in set) {
        if (set.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
            getSeqs(set[c]);
        }
    }

    return seqs.longest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done easily with REGEX. You should use a nested loop.

**[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/SzVcw/2)**

The code used in this example:

```
function similarity(str1, str2) {
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {    //Loop through the letters of the first string
        for (j = i+1; j <= str1.length; j++) {   //Loop through the letters of the first string, starting from the letter in i.
            sub = str1.substring(i, j); //Slice the first string from i to j.
            //console.log(sub, count, str2.indexOf(sub), j, i);
            if (str2.indexOf(sub) != -1) {  //If the sliced string is found in the second string
                if (count < sub.length) { //If the count I currently have is lower then the current match I found
                    count = sub.length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
alert(similarity('zzomg', 'omg'));
```

There aren't as many iterations as I thought. There're `n+(n-1)+n(n-2)+... = n^2-n` It should be fine with not hysterical strings (like 50 letters).

Comment: Maybe not that easy, but seems possible. Have a look at my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function longSubstrings(s1, s2, wbr, casesense){
    var temp= '', long= [], tem, tem2, str1, str2, len= 2, ax, L, i= 0;
    if(s1.length<s2.length){
        tem= s1;
        s1= s2;
        s2= tem;
    }
    // whole words match faster, if appropriate:
    wbr= wbr? ' ':'';
    // you can force a case sensitive match:
    str1= !casesense? s1.toLowerCase():s1;  
    str2= !casesense? s2.toLowerCase():s2;

    // normalize spaces:
    str1= str1.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ');

    str2= str2.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ');
    if(str1.indexOf(str2)!= -1) return s2;
    str1= str1.split(wbr);
    L= str1.length;
    while(i<L){
        tem= tem2= str1[i];
        ax= str2.indexOf(tem);
        while(ax!= -1){
            ++i;
            if(tem2.length>= len){
                len= tem2.length;
                long= long.filter(function(itm){
                    return itm.length>= len;
                });
                long.push(tem2);
            }
            tem2+= wbr+str1[i];
            ax= str2.indexOf(tem2);
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return long;
}
var s1= 'oie ja s a n y t nc eedjib n ife ks aio m io gna  red dogext x ia a dso zcq a a w eadz tie s matsa fw t seno e se pi iz t s j sv b n is t h toa p q osrf o tj e s ine to e io no xo sss jfytai oooic v puieo nnoveya ktnxk atl endtan uiu n s i enhro a a w k s s nlno iai ouex a t pals tnshp ia ais ga dnog rewen z ia bs t bbnn yeq sviiaio tto qe tnoimetn ntsoei i nsut oteh r iynnw ee gos moemtehlt k az q ri svft sc oot naagtc asste nl';
var s2= 'q meael a n o oia d fntqss ne assto nxs n y nx aoeog pho ev t n ao ste o it eoshi j aii x s infs g a il nho t alj ot isw ic ae si k oorateaw ts iug t b oi tn i m e vnos ss o jtn enoik kaon zseeaaitialsu ej a in ays t a nzyv m ibst sxuse t l eto od zs e y os zvinaieks w wq to ce ia ufs v k mrz e n taen d endtbatn tpteiu f gx hboati m o iieac op nef t atyno n p iatb cqaicsn d tt po r oae n n gsq nrne oe ij  red doga st eowsiie snhr';



    longSubstrings(s1, s2);
    //checks by character
    // returned value: (Array)
    red dog

    longSubstrings(s1, s2, 1);
    //checks whole words
    //returned value: (Array)
    red


// Older browsers need a shim for the filter method.
(or just write a loop for the filter)

if(![].filter){

        Array.prototype.filter= function(fun, scope){
            var T= this, A= [], i= 0, itm, L= T.length;
            if(typeof fun== 'function'){
                while(i< L){
                    if(i in T){
                        itm= T[i];
                        if(fun.call(scope, itm, i, T)) A[A.length]= itm;
                    }
                    ++i;
                }
            }
            return A;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The Regex free version

```
chaine1 = "bread";
chaine2 = "read";
if(chaine1.length <= chaine2.length){
    count = chaine1.length;
} 
else{
    count = chaine2.length;

}

var numberOfCharacterMatching = 0;

for (var i =0; i<count; i++){
if(chaine1.charAt(i) == chaine1.charAt(i)){
numberOfCharacterMatching++
}

}
alert(numberOfCharacterMatching++);
```

Comment: Your code fails on "omgzomg" vs "omgomg" (should return 3, returns 6 instead)